# Show parameter of an element on React js dynamically

Tags: reactjs

Using **Formik**, I have created a form that works fine, but to handle the submission I want to paint the onSubmit parameter on the form element if a variable of the state is true.

The state is the following:

```
this.state = {
 formDataOk: false,
}
```

After validating all the inputs of the form, if everything is fine `formDataOk` is changed to true. When this happens I am trying to show the `onSubmit` parameter this way:

```
<Form {this.state.formDataOk && onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}}>
```

Where `handleSubmit` is a function.

Comment: Have you tried `<Form onSubmit={this.state.formDataOk ? this.handleSubmit : undefined}>`?

Comment: @Tholle Tried that, but whenever is set to `undefined` the form is submitted via GET, so all the information is shown on the URL.

Comment: Alright. You could try e.g. `onSubmit={this.state.formDataOk ? this.handleSubmit : (e) => e.preventDefault()}` or check in the `handleSubmit` method if the form is invalid instead.